# Problem in updating post status by clicking checkbox using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have following `tb_posts` table:

```
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| post_id |         post_title          |          post_url           | post_sort_order | post_status |
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|       1 | Mooching in Mooloolaba      | mooching-in-mooloolaba      |               1 |           1 |
|       2 | Back in Townsville          | back-to-the-boat            |               2 |           1 |
|       3 | Re Naming                   | re-naming                   |               3 |           0 |
|       4 | Henry                       | henry                       |               4 |           1 |
|       5 | Magnetic Island             | magnetic-island             |               5 |           0 |
|       6 | Arriving in the Whitsundays | arriving-in-the-whitsundays |               6 |           1 |
|       7 | Back in Townsville          | townsville                  |               7 |           1 |
|       8 | Headboards                  | improving-the-cabins        |               8 |           1 |
|       9 | A great weekend             | a-great-weekend             |               9 |           1 |
|      10 | Headboard                   | headboard                   |              10 |           1 |
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Here's my PHP code in `index.php`:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_posts`";
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $query);
// If at least one record found
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
?>
    <form name="frm1" method="get" action="">
        <table border="1" width="50%" align="center" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5"><h2>Posts</h2></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Order</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $srno = 1;
            // Fetch table rows
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {
                $post_id = $row['post_id'];
                $status = $row['post_status'] == 1 ? "checked='checked'" : '';
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['post_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['post_title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['post_url'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chkstatus' value='" . $row['post_status'] . "' $status onClick='changeStatus($post_id, this.value);' /></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeStatus(id, status)
{
    alert(id);
    alert(status);
    document.frm1.action = "update.php?id="+id+"&status="+status;
    document.frm1.submit();
}
</script>
```

The `update.php` file has following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['status']))
{
    $post_id = $_GET['id'];
    $post_status = $_GET['status'];
    $post_status = $post_status == 1 ? 0 : 1;

    echo $query = "UPDATE `tb_posts` SET `post_status` = $post_status WHERE `post_id` = $post_id";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

So basically here I am representing posts in a HTML table from my database. The HTML table has one column `status` which has a checkbox for each post row. If the `post_status` is 1 then the corresponding checkbox will be checked otherwise it will be unchecked (for `post_status` = 0).

I am trying to update post status via JavaScript. When a checkbox is clicked, its corresponding post status and post id will be sent to `update.php` after submitting form via JavaScript. And in `update.php` the UPDATE query will run accordingly.

But for unknown reason, when I try to do all this, after clicking a checkbox, the page redirects to

`update.php?chkstatus=1&chkstatus=1&chkstatus=0&chkstatus=1&chkstatus=1&chkstatus=1&chkstatus=1&chkstatus=1&chkstatus=1`

and a blank screen appears. Not even the query is printed. And when I hit back button, then the clicked checkbox's post row is not updated. I am really don't understand what's causing this issue.

Where am I doing it wrong here? Is this approach good (if we consider only PHP and JavaScript)? Is there any other better way or logic to do this all seamlessly?

Comment: Replace setting the form's action and submitting it with `location = "update.php?id=" + id + "&status=" + status;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the form-action to `update.php`,

```
document.frm1.action = "update.php?id="+id+"&status="+status;
```

However on submitting, the form overwrites the get-parameters with the contents of the form since you use `method="get"` in your form.

Try setting your form to `method="post"`, so the forms contents won't interfere with the get-parameters.

Comment: I think you spotted the bug in my code. I changed form's method attribute to `post` and my code really worked. I don't understand who downvoted you.